# How can store html DOM elements with applied inputed values as string

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to store div as a whole in DB. After then I'd like to preview this page from the stored string value in DB.
If I use `$(selector).html()` then I can get only HTML elements with not apply inputed value.
Suppose my page is writed as follows.

```
<div id="test_div">
    <span>this is test</span>
    <select>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
    <textarea>This is test</textarea>
</div>
```

I input some text in the Text area and select a special option in the Select box.
After then I want to store this page state as a string.

I write code as following and save this in DB.

```
var content = $("#test_div").html();
```

But I can't get applied value.

I want to get like this. (When I select option3 and add text "Welcome!" in textarea)

```
    <span>this is test</span>
    <select>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3" selected>option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
    <textarea>This is test. Welcome!</textarea>
```

How can I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Why tie the data directly to the presentation layer? Wouldn't it make more sense to just store the appropriate values (ie `3`) in the DB?

Comment: I have a very irregular dynamic set of input tag and table in my form. I have to store this and have to show these states later. The design of the database is impossible or requires a lot of effort. So I decided to do it like these methods

Comment: I wouldn't store a bunch of HTML as data. It seems like a lazy solution that will end up costing data. Just store the values. Build the DOM on the Client-side, since you want a dynamic solution anyways. I don't see any AJAX or MySQL *(or any database language)* here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was wrong to attempt it.
The design itself was wrong and that doing so caused many problems.
The customer who required this method proposed a different method and solved the problem by storing all information from the table as individual tables.**